# Converging sequence, $\limsup \neq \ \liminf$

Tags: general-topology, limits

Am i mixing up concepts by saying that given the topological space $(\mathbb{R}, \{\emptyset,\mathbb{R}\}$), the sequence $(-1)^n$ has:
$$\liminf = -1<\limsup = 1$$
But the sequence converges. Is this a valid counterexample to the implication:

> $a_n$ converges $\implies$ $\liminf a_n = \limsup a_n$

Assuming that this statement is given with this little context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the topology is not Hausdorff, nothing stops the sequence from converging to multiple elements, and indeed in this case the sequence converges to every single element in $\mathbb{R}$. If you define the lim sup and inf to be the smallest and greatest cluster points then they don’t exist.